# Checkbox status checked issue

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I have a page that displays information of pizza (id, name, innards, price) **view-pizza-item.jsp**

I have servlet for view-pizza-item.jsp which is called: **ViewPizzaServlet.java**

I have editing page for the Pizza with tons of checkboxes for each innards material (meat, cheese, etc) **edit-pizza-item.jsp**

I have editing servlet for the editing page: **EditPizzaServlet.java**

My issue is that, i want to have the innards checkboxes in edit-pizza-item.jsp to be checked if the pizza has the said innards in **view-pizza-items.jsp**

Basically if the pizza has "Oregano" in earlier page, i want the "Oregano" checkbox to be checked in the editing page when i open it up.

Any idea how can i do this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with servlets, but in most web development languages you would pass the information in a cookie or URL parameter.

Comment: As above, I don't use servlets but session would probably be way to go: [servlet session tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-session-tracking.htm)

Comment: you can maintain array of flag for each check box. and then sent array to your other page. A little logic will do the work.

Comment: In fact you can use request attributes. For each ingredient something like `request.setAttribute("oregano","yes")`. In the view-pizza-items.jsp you can set up a for loop and just test each ingredient if a corresponding attribute has been set. If so, then set that checkbox to checked otherwise leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set into your user session the object bean 'pizza' which is going to be shared between your servlets like this:

```
httpRequest.getSession().setAttribute('pizza', pizza);
```

Answer (score 0):

you know in advance that a certain type of pizza will have specific toppings, so when the user is willing to edit his/her margherita pizza you can simply load the object instance from the back-end just the way you do to show it in the `view-pizza-item.jsp`.

Now you have several options, but I would follow this approach: I'd leverage JavaScript to manipulate the Pizza model and AJAX to issue an HTTP call (POST or PUT) to persist changes for that specific Pizza instance.

Of course, you have to set up an endpoint able to serve such HTTP call. The endpoint could store the pizza modification which are ready to be displayed in a separate summary view. That's it.